# android Alarm expandableListView With Automatic Update

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, expandablelistview

hi guys i have an expandable list view with bunch of items on it when a item clicked an alarm will set for the item time but because its too much alarms and i cant tell my client to go change the alarm by your self then i wrote a database with a update code for each item and when the update code(from server) is not equal to the database one alarm will cancel and set a new one but its not working and also it will cancel all the list alarms no errors too i dont know why this is my code getChildView for expandableListView adapter(working before update code changes)

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildTour child =  getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ex_list_tours_child, null);


    }

    CheckAlarms(context,groupPosition,childPosition,dbHelper);

    return convertView;

}
```

active code is the alarm active code 
and this is CheckAlarms method

```
public void CheckAlarms(Context context, int groupPostion, int childPostion, exToursDbHelper dbHelper){
    ChildTour child =  getChild(groupPostion,
            childPostion);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,child.getTourId(),intent,0);
    int dbUpdateCode=  dbHelper.getUpdateCode(child.getTourId());
    if (dbUpdateCode != child.getUpdateCode() && dbHelper.getActive(child.getTourId()) == 1 ){
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, child.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, child.getMin());
        intent.putExtra("prize",child.getPrize());
        intent.putExtra("gameMode",child.getGameMode());
        intent.putExtra("time",child.getTime());
        intent.putExtra("tourId",child.getTourId());
        intent.putExtra("siteurl",child.getmSiteUrl());
        time=(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time)
        {
            if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
            else
                time = time + (1000*60*60*24);
        }
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, pendingIntent);
        dbHelper.UpdateCode(child.getTourId(),child);
        Log.i("database","alarm with Id " +child.getTourId()+"is Updated");
    }
    Log.i("database","updateCode : "+child.getUpdateCode()+" databaseUpdate Code: "+dbUpdateCode);
}
```

i wants to know why not working and if thanks to you guys its worked is this the standard way?

this is the logs

```
    01-09 05:33:33.482 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:33:33.502 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 4 databaseUpdate Code: 4
01-09 05:33:33.522 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:33:33.532 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:33:33.552 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:33:33.562 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:33:33.582 23779-23779/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
```

and after changing update code

```
    01-09 05:34:42.462 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:34:42.482 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: alarm with Id 2is Updated
01-09 05:34:42.482 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 5 databaseUpdate Code: 4
01-09 05:34:42.492 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:34:42.512 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:34:42.522 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:34:42.542 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
01-09 05:34:42.552 25303-25303/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: updateCode : 1 databaseUpdate Code: 1
```

if needs anything else tell me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a custom object and add it as a tag (`getTag`) to the views in your list to track state from there, this way you can adequately observe on click if you need to set of unset a given alarm.

```
public class AlarmState = {
    public boolean isOn = false;
    public Date changeDate;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ChildTour child =  getChild(groupPosition,
        childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ex_list_tours_child, null);
        AlarmState alarm = new AlarmState;
        alarm.isOn = true;
        alarm.changeDate = new Date();
        convertView.setTag(alarm);

    }

    CheckAlarms(context,groupPosition,childPosition,dbHelper);

    return convertView;

}
```

then you can add a click handler to your list activity

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            AlarmState alarm = (AlarmState)view.getTag();
            if (alarm.isOn) {
              // send braodcast to turn it off
            else {
              // send braodcast to turn it on
            }
        }
    });
```